# Parallel programming in Dual-Core processed by one core

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

I have an AMD Athlon II P320 Dual-Core Processor 2.10 GHz.

I'm trying to run the following program but it seems that it is processed by just one core.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main (void){
    int i;

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for ( i = 1; i < 100; i++){
        printf("%d ", i);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
}
```

I'm expecting the output to be the first 99 number in a random order but the my output is the first 99 numbers in ascendent order. What's the problem here?

Comment: How are you compiling that code?

Comment: If you are using gcc, compile your code with `-fopenmp`, and your code will work as you are expecting it to work.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and I didn't change anything in the compiler options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tested on a dual-core (or setting `omp_set_num_threads(2)` on quad or more cores) and *Windows*, and I am able to see you result. For ChirsBD's answer, compilers cannot ignore such `printf`. The OP's code will be parallelized and will be run in parallel.

1. You are using the default OpenMP's static scheduling and using 2 cores. So, the first core will print out from 1 to 50, and the other prints from 51 to 100. But, the observation is that you can't see some races.
2. `printf` and `fflush` will be serialized even if you don't a explicit critical section. So, the first thread is highly likely to acquire that mutex, and the second thread would be blocked.
3. However, the computation, which is a simple `printf`, is too short. So, while the second thread is blocked for the first attempt to acquire the critical section, the first thread just prints the entire numbers. That means, {the time of acquiring and releasing the critical section 50 times} < {the time of a minimum blocking of the second thread}.
4. If you put a dummy compuation such as `for (volatile int k = 0; k < 100; ++k);`, you will see interleaving, but still lock steped: the output will mostly be `"1 51 2 52 ..."`.
5. However, when I run this code on Linux, **I see some random ordering**. This is because the implementation and internal locking of stdout in Linux may be different from Windows.

To summarize, such serialization is because of the implementation `printf` and too short computation in a parallel loop. Thus, it is *not* a problem.

Comment: I tried it your way but it still doesn't work. Can you provide me a complete example? Thanks!

Comment: "Doesnt'work" means you still see sorted output? I just copied your code and run it on Linux (gcc) and Windows (VS 2010). Windows's result is sorted. But, I observed randomness in Linux.

Comment: I'm on Windows 7 64, and I'm compiling it in Visual Studio 2010. The result is sorted.

Comment: Yes, that's what I see. And, this is not a problem. You don't need to worry about that :)

Comment: Ok but how can I be sure that my result will be correct in a bigger enviroment or if the parallel tags are used correctly?

Comment: This example is really small and meaningless, so don't worry. If you have a serious computation, then dual core should will be mostly okay to verify the correctness. But, predicting the scalability may not be easy.

Answer (score 1):

Parellizing such a loop is void because of the `printf` that you are doing on the same output stream. Output to such a stream is mutexed, so even if openMP manages to launch separate threads, they will be force to access sequentially to that resource.

Have the threads write in different files, each, and you might see a difference. But to really see one, you should have something in the inner part that is compute bound and not IO bound.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that because it's such a simple process that the compiler optimisation takes precedence.

Try writing it as a recursive function call to itself instead of a loop and see what happens then.

Comment: Parallelizing a recursive call is pretty hard. And that code does output in "random" order on my machine. I suspect the problem is elsewhere...

Comment: So obviously an issue with the compiler or elsewhere in the OPs setup.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting that output is because by default openMP uses a static partitioning. So for two cores, it will partition the interval 0..100 into 0..50 and 51..100. Now, since the interval is really small, printing 50 numbers by one thread will (most likely) occur before the other thread even manages to start. That's why you see continuous numbers and not interleaving.